# Windows key stops working on windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-key

I seem to have an intermittent issue with my windows key. While this works shortly after booting, it stops working after a short time.

I have tried `sfc` and various `dism` commands to try and resurrect it, but with no joy.

Are there any other potential fixes or troubleshooters that I could try? I'm at a bit of a loss here.

Comment: 1. Test with another keyboard. 2. Check if you have other software "stealing" key presses, e.g., AutoHotkey.

Comment: I've tried another keyboard but that has the same problem.